# Swimming Medley Relay Time Simulation Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, vba, excel, time

I am trying to simulate the I/O of this [website page](http://www.swimcoachtools.com/Relays.aspx)

My Input sheet looks like this:

[image]

Now after taking the values from input sheet and arranging them in ascending order I got this in a temp worksheet :

[image]

This is what my results sheet looks like:

[image]

Now I have tried this after sorting process(didn't add code for sorting since it's not the problem):

```
Set rng = Union(wTime.Range("D6:D25"), wTime.Range("F6:F25"), wTime.Range("H6:H25"), wTime.Range("J6:J25"))
cnt1 = 1: cnt2 = 1: cnt3 = 1: cnt4 = 1

wTime.Range("A6:A25") = Empty   'Ticker

For i = 1 To 20

bckStroke(i) = wTemp.Range("A" & i + 1).Value
brstStroke(i) = wTemp.Range("C" & i + 1).Value
btrFly(i) = wTemp.Range("E" & i + 1).Value
frStyle(i) = wTemp.Range("G" & i + 1).Value

wTime.Range("A6:A25") = Empty

For Each cel In rng

If cel.Column = 4 And cel.Value = bckStroke(i) And cel.Value <> 0 And Trim(wTime.Cells(cel.Row, 1)) <> "Y" And cnt1 < 6 Then
    wRes.Cells((cnt1 + 5 + (cnt1 - 1) * 2) - 1, 4) = wTime.Cells(cel.Row, 2)    'Athlete Name
    wRes.Cells(cnt1 + 5 + (cnt1 - 1) * 2, 4) = bckStroke(i)                     'Time
    cnt1 = cnt1 + 1
    wTime.Cells(cel.Row, 1) = "Y"
End If

If cel.Column = 6 And cel.Value = brstStroke(i) And cel.Value <> 0 And Trim(wTime.Cells(cel.Row, 1)) <> "Y" And cnt2 < 6 Then
    wRes.Cells((cnt2 + 5 + (cnt2 - 1) * 2) - 1, 6) = wTime.Cells(cel.Row, 2)    'Athlete Name
    wRes.Cells(cnt2 + 5 + (cnt2 - 1) * 2, 6) = brstStroke(i)                    'Time
    cnt2 = cnt2 + 1
    wTime.Cells(cel.Row, 1) = "Y"
End If

If cel.Column = 8 And cel.Value = btrFly(i) And cel.Value <> 0 And Trim(wTime.Cells(cel.Row, 1)) <> "Y" And cnt3 < 6 Then
    wRes.Cells((cnt3 + 5 + (cnt3 - 1) * 2) - 1, 8) = wTime.Cells(cel.Row, 2)    'Athlete Name
    wRes.Cells(cnt3 + 5 + (cnt3 - 1) * 2, 8) = btrFly(i)                        'Time
    cnt3 = cnt3 + 1
    wTime.Cells(cel.Row, 1) = "Y"
End If

If cel.Column = 10 And cel.Value = frStyle(i) And cel.Value <> 0 And Trim(wTime.Cells(cel.Row, 1)) <> "Y" And cnt4 < 6 Then
    wRes.Cells((cnt4 + 5 + (cnt4 - 1) * 2) - 1, 10) = wTime.Cells(cel.Row, 2)   'Athlete Name
    wRes.Cells(cnt4 + 5 + (cnt4 - 1) * 2, 10) = frStyle(i)                      'Time
    cnt4 = cnt4 + 1
    wTime.Cells(cel.Row, 1) = "Y"
End If

Next cel

Next i
```

> I just want to know the simplest logic to get the desired result after arranging them in ascending order (refer temp sheet) it should be easy but I can't seem to understand it.

Conditions that I know of for now:

1. Each team should have unique swimmers (i.e 4 Unique names in each team)
2. A swimmer can appear in other team as well if he has best time in other category as well. (E.g. Marcelo will appear in top 4 team since he has the best time in all 4 categories)
3. Teams with shortest time should be placed 1st in the list on result sheet. I think sorting in ascending order takes care of this it's matter of selecting right swimmer from the temp sheet list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

 4. Relay Logic premise: ***Get all the combinations possible without 2 identical strings. And then sort them lowest to largest.*** I'd do the following: Get all the possible combinations and their sum with the following: *Combinations may still be buggy, since it may be variable to how many numbers you may have. This is just a guide to describe the process
[image]
[image]

```
Sub Combinations()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, l As Long, m As Long, n As Long, o As Long, p As Long, q As Long
    Dim CountComb As Long, lastrow As Long

    Range("K2").Value = Now - 5

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    CountComb = 0: lastrow = 6

    For i = 1 To 6: For j = 1 To 5
    For k = 1 To 6: For l = 1 To 6
    If Not (i = j Or i = k Or i = l Or j = k Or j = l Or k = l) Then

              Range("K" & lastrow).Value = Range("A" & i).Value & "/" & _
                                     Range("B" & j).Value & "/" & _
                                     Range("C" & k).Value & "/" & _
                                     Range("D" & l).Value
        lastrow = lastrow + 1
        CountComb = CountComb + 1
        End If
    Next: Next
    Next: Next

    Range("K1").Value = CountComb
    Range("K3").Value = Now + 21

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
Function TimeSum(Persons As String, Chr As String) As Double
Dim ArrayPersons() As String: ArrayPersons = Split(Persons, Chr)
Dim SumOfTime As Double
Dim ItemPerson As Variant
Dim NumberRoutines As Long: NumberRoutines = 2
Const SheetData = "Sheet1"
For Each ItemPerson In ArrayPersons
SumOfTime = Sheets(SheetData).Columns(NumberRoutines).Find(ItemPerson).Offset(0, -1).Value + SumOfTime
NumberRoutines = NumberRoutines + 2
Next ItemPerson
TimeSum = SumOfTime
End Function
```

Maybe you could define better the sub to do what you desire for, but, the last coding could guide you in the right path. In a second thought, you could get combinations in a dictionary instead. 
[[image: 3]]
[[image: 2]]

Comment: No it's not about just taking the names of the person in ascending order of their times. Did you see the I/O of this http://www.swimcoachtools.com/Relays.aspx website ?

Comment: Could you care to explain what's the logic behind the relay then?